# window.frame.openDialog does not work on MAC OS

Tags: javascript, appjs

window.frame.openDialog does not work on MAC OS. I couldn't select the files from Open dialog box. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean it does not work in Safari instead ? which version ?